# Swagger is not returning authorization token

Tags: token, l5-swagger

Swagger is not returning authorization token! but it's working fine in Postman.
Even if I am printing verify token it returns empty string.

My Function Code.

```
$verified_token = str_replace('Bearer ', '', $request->header('Authorization'));
        return $verified_token;
```

Swagger Response is empty due to which I cannot do further validations.

Thanks

I have tried reading documentation for swagger but couldn't found any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your are defining security field in swagger code. For example if you are using sanctum as middleware define like this.

```
/**
     * @OA\Get(
     ...
     *  security={ {"sanctum": {} }},
     ...
```